# Precise contour finding algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, interpolation, contour, bicubic

My task at hand is finding specific contours in a cloud of points. They need to be determined as accurately as possible. Therefore higher order polynomial interpolation must be used. I have data consisting of points in a grid, each point having its own height.

I had great success finding contours with *matplotlib.contours* function. Then I directly used *matplotlib.cntr* (C++ algorithm) to determine specific contours. But because the file uses marching squares algorithm (linear interpolation) the precision of found contours is not good enough.

I am looking for alternative ways to solve this problem. A suggested solution was to

- Use bicubic interpolation to find analytical function around a specific point.
- Followed by calculation of the function derivative.
- Derived function is then used to determine direction in which derivative stays at 0 (using point as a point of view). By moving a small distance in that direction height should remain constant.

Using this algorithm a contour should be found. Would this algorithm work, can I take any shortcuts when implementing it (by using already implemented functions)?

Implementing this algorithm would take quite the effort on my part, and besides  it may only work in theory.  I am guessing that the numerical error should still be present (the derivative may not be exactly 0) and may in the end even surpass the current one (using marching squares). I want to consider other, easier and faster methods to solve this problem.

What other algorithm could be used to solve it?

Did anyone ever face a similar problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: The problem is ill-formulated, as depending on the interpolation of the height function the contour could be "anything", I'd think variations of `O(dx^2)` between different interpolation methods. // You could, as still another alternative, compute some kind of gradient field from your data, use bilinear interpolation on it, and solve an ODE for the vector field orthogonal to it to get some curvy contour line.